# Remove substring from one column in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, substring

I want to delete a part of the substring from my table's column

For example, I have a structure like the following:

```
id | Col1                                      
____________________________________________________________
1  | The string I want and the string I don't
```

And I need to update my table such that:

```
id | Col1                                       
____________________________________________________________
1  | The string I want
```

I tried using the following code:

```
$var = "UPDATE mytable
  SET col1 = replace(col1,col1(SUBSTRING(col1,19),'')";
```

But this won't work!

Comment: Things to research Substring,substring_index,replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query to separate address:

```
UPDATE mytable as a 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        id,
        Address1, 
        LEFT(Address1, 40 -1) as newCol1,
        substring(Address1, 40) as newCol2
    FROM mytable 
    where length(Address1) > 40) b 
on a.id=b.id 
set Address1=newCol1,Address2=newCol2;
```

if there is any concern about above query please let me know.

Comment: I don't need to switch to another column after the comma, I need to switch after a 40 character limit. Intelligent approach though!

Comment: @Devratna's query would still apply, just substitute your hard limit of 40 for the POSITION functions.

Comment: "id" is just my auto incrementing primary key, which I specifically did not create in my csv file(As I am converting my csv into MySQL table), So It's throwing an "Unkown column" error.

Comment: I think you should convert your CSV into MySQL first and then run this query to update fields.

Comment: Ok thanks, and incase I have another column called Address3, how can I impose same restrictions on Address2?
Will this still work?

Comment: yes it works just replace Address1 -> Address2 and Address2 -> Address3